# addClass to a wrapAll result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this `date-picker` box, which I added a calendar image to it using `wrapAll`, picture below is the result:

[image: Date-Picker]

Here is my code:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".date-picker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
  });

  $(".date-picker").each(function() {
    $(this).add($(this).next()).wrapAll('<div class="imageInputWrapper"></div>');
  });
});
```

```css
.imageInputWrapper {
  width: 172px;
  border: solid 1px white;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 #C2C2C2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form:input class="date-picker" type="text" path="fromDate" style="width: 130px; height: 41px; background-color: white; border: none; outline: none; margin-left:5px" />

<img src="/resources/img/calendar.png" id="fromDateImgId"></td>
```

Now, I want to check if the user did not insert any date or the inserted date is invalid, using `addClass` add a red border to the whole picture above, with this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submitCreateCampaignForm").submit(function(e) {

    var $form = $(this);
    var errors = 0;
    var fromDate = $form.find("input[name=fromDate]").val()

    if (fromDate == "") {
      $form.find("input[name=fromDate]").addClass("red");
      errors++;
    }

    if (errors) e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
.imageInputWrapper {
  width: 172px;
  border: solid 1px white;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 #C2C2C2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form:input class="date-picker" type="text" path="fromDate" style="width: 130px; height: 41px; background-color: white; border: none; outline: none; margin-left:5px" />

<img src="/resources/img/calendar.png" id="fromDateImgId"></td>
```

but the result I get is this:

[image: wrapAll Error]

How can I add the red border to the whole resulting of `wrapAll`?

This is the code in the jsFiddle, unfortunately I could not add my `form:input` functionality to the `Next` button:

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reshadgp/qndnvff2/)

Comment: Is there a chance to check the code on the live page?

Comment: Try to put them into a div with a specific class.

Comment: @John unfortunately it's a long form and it will be really long if I want to write the whole code. But if it's really necessary I will do that

Comment: Please share a [mcve], or at least the generated DOM structure.

Comment: Ok I will add the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this:

```
$form.find("input[name=fromDate]").parent().addClass("red");
```

You need to target the parent element (your wrapper)

### EDIT

Fiddle working: https://jsfiddle.net/1otwoxsp/2/

Comment: Did not work. I added the jsfiddle to the end of the code.

Comment: It works, but you are making wrong code in many places. See this fiddle working: https://jsfiddle.net/1otwoxsp/2/

Comment: Thanksss ! now works fine ! In changing the logic of the next button I made some errors.

Comment: Things you are making wrong: input date have no `name` attribute (you are using `path`). Next button is not the form and you have no `<form>` tag. you are adding `red` class to input, not wrapper. That's because you have some errors. See that problems and take care with the selectors and targets.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the input and the image tags inside a div tag, and you would add the "red" class to that div, which will englobe both tags and the effect will be the expected.